# Can't buy power from neighboring city

Tags: simcity-2013

I have two cities in a region. One is out of power and all my services have shutdown, and the other city has a coal power plant with a ton of extra power.

I purchased buy from city A to city B, but nothing is happening. When I go to the region view and look at the stats for buying the power. It says `Using 0 MW/154.3 MW for $0`.

I thought maybe it was a server issue, but it's been like this now for two days.

See image below.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I'm confused. Most of my city is red without power, but the power stats say `Needed 42 MW, 106 Capacity. With 64.5 excess`

What is going on? My solar power plant says it's shut down because of a lack of workers, but I need power to get workers.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I shutdown both power plants, and now it says `-40 deficit` but it's still not buying power from the other city.

**EDIT:**

Great. Now my power plants won't power back up and the entire city is dead. This game sucks.

Comment: I asked earlier but then realized it's just because regions are still broken. Sometimes it works, most of the time it doesn't. Just wait for the fix I say.

Comment: I feel like a beta tester.

Comment: You know, you might have more luck trying a game on one of the newer servers. I tried to play on one of the Day 1 servers and my region just fell apart. I started a new game on one of the newly added servers and it's a definite improvement. Though, I haven't started a second city yet to test neighbor deals.

Comment: Nope, still not working. I've built up a modest city in a private region. Started another city in the same region and neighbor deals are still not working, no other bonuses are in effect either (e.g., regional benefits of town halls, trade, etc.). We should not have to put up with this...

Comment: @JeffMercado Well, at least we get a free game?

Comment: @JonathanGleason I'm sure it's a game that requires a constant connection.

Comment: By the way, the problem has seem to gone away for me.  It seems like this might have coincided with the upgrade from a Town Hall to a City Hall?  Can you confirm that a City Hall is necessary (and sufficient) to trade between neighbors in the region?

Comment: @JonathanGleason: I had a city hall in my first game, I'll try to build up to it on my other game on one of the newer servers. We'll see how that goes.

Comment: Both my cities have a City Hall and they weren't trading, but I read they completed some server updates this weekend. So hopefully that translates into bug fixes for this.

Comment: It appears to work now! Not only am I getting power, but now people are moving between the cities including the mayors.

Comment: What server are you on? I'm using `North America East 2`. I'm so tired of switching server. I wish there was a feature to move all your cities to the same server.

Comment: I'm playing on NA West 4.  If only we could load/save... then we could actually experiment.

Comment: Yea, while I said it's working, I'm now unable to load my region to play it. I can log into the server, but can't play my cities. I was able to load other people's cities and view them. This sucks.

Comment: So it looks like some neighbor deals are working. I'm finally able to buy/sell services to my neighbors. Though, it seems like the services you need to most, the rate at which you use them sucks. One city needs sewage to be taken care of. Another has plenty of capacity for it. The first city cannot send all the sewage out at a fast enough rate, it is still backing up. At least we're making progress...

Comment: I think things like that are limited to the number of trucks you have, except there are no sewage trucks. So I don't know how that works. I also notice, that it sends things to other cities without me even approving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your city is out of power for whatever reason it seems to take a while after you get a power plant online for power to reach the entire city.  First a power plant has to get workers, then after that it seems to take a while before it actually starts supplying power.

Buying power from other cities may be buggy.  I played a city for several hours buying power from neighboring cities; then saved and reloaded that city the next day only to find the city without power despite power still being available in the region (it is possible that not enough power was available) so I broke down and built a power plant and observed the city slowly get powered up.

Comment: Power plants generate "power agents" which are those little yellow dots you see darting around the grid with the power data overlay on. These power agents make completely 100% random turns at intersections until they are consumed by a building that is not at full power. This is primarily the reason why it takes a while for the other side of the city to "turn back on" after a power outage.

Answer (score 1):

It's a communist nation.  Resources are split between all the cities in the region even if nobody owns it yet, so you don't have the freedom to choose.  It doesn't matter who earned it.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the buying city must not have any power producers that have the "sell to region" box checked. Once I unchecked this in the power producers in the buying city then that city started to import power.