# How do regions handle the division of excess utility capacities?

Tags: simcity-2013

I have two cities in a region. The old one has plenty of water, electricity and sewage treatment resources to spare. The second city I want to specialize, and not use up precious room for these utilities.

In the second city, Im warned for a water deficit. Clicking on the water button I can see Im lacking 6.9 and the GUI reports that there is 45.2 available in the region.

My problem now is although the new city buys all these resources from the old one, it doesn't buy enough. I cannot see any pattern in it. It might be a server issue, but I would expect it to not setup any trade at all if thats the case. Im getting some water, just not all I need nor all thats avilable.

What am I missing?

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108110/cant-buy-power-from-neighboring-city

Comment: I've got the same problem with water, my first city is heavily populated plus education and has to buy extra water from my second city which I assumed would be a valid design. I setup a massive excess of available water in my second city but my first city doesn't buy enough, it's about 50 kg/hr short yet there is over 200 available? Power works fine so it would appear to be a bug unless it's a special undocumented mechanic limiting water flow on the regional roads.

Comment: @mizipzor - The tutorial explained how to do this.

Comment: @Ramhound I did what the tutorial said, and I think I did it right because there is *some* transfer, the city just doesnt buy enough to cover its needs despite there being plentufil avilable.

Comment: @mizipzor - I can't explain the reason your not buying enough, jsut know, the tutoral explains how to do so.

Comment: I can think of two possibilities: (1) power is bought in blocks, you won't able to actually get the higher amount until the next refresh -- (monthly?) (2) someone else in the region is buying the extra capacity.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108110/cant-buy-power-from-neighboring-city as the linked question has more to do with release server issues than how the feature is intended to work.

Answer (score 8):

Before answering the question directly, you need to understand a sparsely documented caveat to region play... region hubs.

**Excess utility capacity is divided up equally amongst city sites in a region hub.** A region hub is defined, for utility purposes, as any city connected by ROAD to a city that wants to provided utilities to other cities.

A typical region hub in the Simcity world has 4 city sites connected to it by road. Some have as many as 7. We will use the example of having 4.

**EXAMPLE:** City A is in a region with 16 city sites, divided into 4 region hubs.

- City A decides to specialize in coal mining, and power itself with a coal power plant using local resources to keep costs down.
- City A only needs 15Mw to operate, but the power plant constantly produces 75 Mw. Giving it 60Mw in excess capacity. This excess capacity is offered to other cities in the region hub.
- The 3 other city sites are given the choice to buy an equal 20Mw share of the excess power since 60 / 3 = 20
- City C and D do not need the excess power, as they are generating it on their own. However, city B wishes to buy more than their share. They do not have this option. City A would need to increase their capacity in order to give out a larger share to City B.

This is how the game currently operates, and it appears to be working as intended.

Comment: My answer is not a place for my opinion, so I will give it in a comment. The way it SHOULD work, is that City A should have full control over how its excess power is distributed, but alas... it is not to be. Maybe it will be patched in.

Comment: It should be where if city C and D also have excess power, then all extra power becomes available to city B, since B is the only city in need of power. If city C expands and needs more power, then the power from A and D should be divided between B and C. The current system should be patched.

Answer (score 1):

From reddit (bug compilation):

> City producing 55 excess water, only able to buy 19.5 water from it. EDIT: this appears to be a feature, splitting the amount between the available regions it can share it's water with. I still consider this a bug, as this is not how sharing should be working IMO.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think a single post in a reddit thread can be considered a reliable source, especially when they go out of date very quickly (unlike wikis and posts on Stack Exchange sites, which can be continuously edited and updated)

Comment: @YiJiang'sEvilClone The source doesn't mean it's not correct. Tater596's answer is exactly the same but with more detail. Can you contradict them?